# Xamarin logo background against app background

Tags: xaml, xamarin

So I am just trying to get my head round Xamarin and I have set the background of the app to be the same colour as the background of my logo.

For some reason, when I add the logo, it picks up a darker shade of blue when within the app. Do anyone know what might cause this?

[image]

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#10ABD9">
            <Image x:Name="gymAppLogo" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="GymApplogo.jpg"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

[image]

Comment: You could post the relevant code , which will be helpful to us to solve the issue .

Comment: I've added it in for you.

Comment: Could you provide the image file ?

Comment: Added for you..

Comment: This is how mine looks.

Comment: It works fine on my side . Which device did you test? And what is the version of Android ?